File Size Increases Dramatically After Upgrading from XLS to XLSM
I have a ".xls" Excel file that contains some VBA code. I want to upgrade it to ".xlsx", but Excel indicates that ".xlsx" files do not support the VBA project, so I upgraded to ".xlsm".
After upgrading to the ".xlsm" file, when I run the VBA code to process some data in the sheets, the file size increases significantly. The file size starts at 100KB and then expands to over 490MB after running the VBA code.
Despite the substantial growth in file size, only a small amount of additional statistical data is added. I'm looking for assistance in identifying the cause of this excessive file size. What could be causing the ".xlsm" file to become so large?

could you post the VBA code you are running? Just to be clear: you run the code first on a xls file and the result is 100Kb, then you run exactly the same code on a xslm file that contains exactly the same data and the result occupies 490Mb instead of 100Kb. Is this correct?

There can be fun and games when a former .xls (that's pre Office 2007) is migrated onto .xlsx if there are any embedded images present (and the wind is blowing in the wrong direction). Typically the file doubles in size with each repeated updating due to accumulation of orphaned images. You need to make a small example that reproduces this effect. I suspect that may be impossible. Try recreating the file from scratch on the new platform. ie export to .html and then load it from there. That should lose any orphaned image data (you may be surprised at the amount of dross in there).
